# JQuery cookie setting takes time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

Following is my code to set cookie.

```
$.removeCookie("myCookie",{ path: '/' });
$.cookie('myCookie', JSON.stringify(args), { expires: 1 });//1.7kb args
```

The below code is followed by the cookie setting.

```
document.forms[0].target = '_blank';
document.forms[0].action = "abc.aspx";
document.forms[0].submit();
```

I read "myCookie" in abc.aspx page_load event.
But i get it null.

It seems that, the redirection to page abc.aspx happens before the cookie is set.

Is there any way i can confirm that redirection should happen after the cookie is set.

Comment: With `setTimeout(function(){
}, 20);` or maybe you could return something when the cookie is set and do a `while(cookieResult != true){ nothing }´

Comment: SetTimeout will be a risk. Becuase i dont know what time interval will work.

Comment: so try the thing with the while